# How to break long array into subarrays returned from functions in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this PHP function in Laravel (in my database seeder):

```
DB::table('table_name')->insert([
   [first_record],
   [second_record],
   ...
   [nth_record]
]);
```

I can't use faker libraries and I need to specify each record. However, I decided to break this method into smaller methods this way:

```
public function run() 
{
    DB::table('table_name')->insert([
       $this->firstMethodToReturnPartOfArray(),
       $this->secondMethodToReturnPartOfArray(),
       ...
       $this->nthMethodToReturnPartOfArray()
    ]);
}

public function firstMethodToReturnPartOfArray()
{
    return [
        [first_record],
        [second_record],
        ...
        [nth_record]
    ];
}

public function secondMethodToReturnPartOfArray()
{
    return [
        [first_record],
        [second_record],
        ...
        [nth_record]
    ];
}
```

But I get this error:

> Array to string conversion
> at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php:524

I'm new to PHP and Laravel. How should I fix this?

Comment: Would it be easier to store the data in a file (JSON for example) and just load the file?  Means you can reduce the code to *load this file*.

Comment: @NigelRen since this is a seeder of a package, that would increase the complexity. Though it's an excellent solution, I want to know what's my PHP syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

The error is that for `insert`, where you have `[first_record],` - you are passing in an array of records (the return values of `firstMethodToReturnPartOfArray` etc is an array of records).

You could merge the results of the two (or more) methods and then use `...` to put the results back into the call

```
DB::table('table_name')->insert([
   ...array_merge($this->firstMethodToReturnPartOfArray(),
         $this->secondMethodToReturnPartOfArray(),
         $this->nthMethodToReturnPartOfArray());
]);
```

(Note that the `...` is intentional and not some form of abbreviation).

Or as I mentioned, load it from a file.